# Set a row value to repeat until the next instance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have received a table of various screens and their sections and section ID values and a sort order.  One type of section is a Heading, and there can be several per screen.  I need to add a column to the table that is the associated Heading, which will reset when the next Heading is found.

I've tried using Lag and Lead, but it only looks back or forward one record, and the number of sections on a screen is variable, and always more than 1.

```
SELECT SCREEN, ID, TYPE, SORT
    , LAG(ID) OVER (ORDER BY SORT) PREVIOUS_TYPE
    , LEAD(ID) OVER (ORDER BY SORT) NEXT_TYPE
   , CASE WHEN ID LIKE 'X%' THEN ID
        ELSE LAG(ID) OVER (ORDER BY SORT) END HEADING
FROM T_1
ORDER BY SORT;
```

Source Data:

```
SCREEN   ID     TYPE      SORT
INPUT    X1     Heading    1
INPUT    C123   Finding    2
INPUT    D937   Text       3
INPUT    X2     Heading    4
INPUT    C31    Search     5
INPUT    G876   Negative   6
INPUT    M3838  Risk       7
OUTPUT   X3     Heading    8
OUTPUT   G72    Map        9
```

Expected Output:

```
SCREEN  HEADING ID     TYPE       SORT
INPUT     X1    X1     Heading     1
INPUT     X1    C123   Finding     2
INPUT     X1    D937   Text        3
INPUT     X2    X2     Heading     4
INPUT     X2    C31    Search      5
INPUT     X2    G876   Negative    6
INPUT     X2    M3838  Risk        7
OUTPUT    X3    X3     Heading     8
OUTPUT    X3    G72    Map         9
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions . . . two levels.  The first assigns groups based on the cumulative count of headings.  The second assigns the value:

```
select t.*,
       max(case when type = 'Heading' then id end) over (partition by grp) as heading_id
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when type = 'Heading' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by sort) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

If you happen to know that the heading ids are increasing (as in the data in your question), you can just use a cumulative `max()`:

```
select t.*
       max(case when type = 'Heading' then id end) over (order by sort) as heading_id
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try breaking this into pieces -- first get the unique headings, then join them to the rest of the data. I couldn't think of a way to make this work with a simple join, so I'm using an `apply` instead:

```
with headings as (
  select SCREEN, [ID], [SORT]
  from T_1
  where [TYPE] = 'Heading'
)
select t_1.[SCREEN], h_1.HEADING, t_1.[ID], t_1.[TYPE], t_1.[SORT]         
from t_1
outer apply (
  select top 1 h.[ID] AS HEADING
  from headings h
  where h.[SCREEN] = t_1.[SCREEN]
    and h.[SORT] <= t_1.[SORT]
  order by h.[SORT] desc
) h_1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fbb75/5

Answer (score 0):

THis should work:

```
  SELECT t.SCREEN, t.ID, t.TYPE, t.SORT,
    (SELECT  TOP 1 h.ID  FROM T_1 h WHERE h.SCREEN=t.SCREEN AND h.SORT<=t.SORT AND h.TYPE='Heading' ORDER BY h.SORT DESC) AS HEADING
    FROM T_1 t
```